# How can I remove button?

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, performance

I have a string with the name of my button. Say it is called `String A`.

```
String A = myButtonName;
```

Now, if I want to remove the button by doing:

```
 layout.removeView(myButtonName);
```

This would work, but, I can't do that on a string.

How can I do it on my string?

Like this, right now I am getting an error, since it is a string:

```
 layout.removeView(A);
```

How can I remove a view with a string which corresponds to a view?

Theoretically, I want to typecast my string to a ViewGroup

---

**Simplified question:**

I have a string. That string is *also* the variable name of my button. 
Can I remove the button using the string?

Comment: What do you mean by name? Do you mean the variable name, or the text on the Button?

Comment: Your String is just holding a variable which is a string, not a button

Comment: Post your layout code and how you get string name

Comment: @MikeM. By name I mean the name of the button. Yes, the variable name.

Comment: @SaiPhani For example, `Button myButtonName`. Now I am trying to remove the button based on the string I have for the button

Comment: @johnrao07 yes, and that's what i'm asking. It is a string variable, but I want to just have it be a variable

Comment: Post your code here so we help you in better way.

Comment: @SuhasBachewar Thanks for your reply. There is no more relevant code to post though, because my question is very short. I have a string. That string is also the variable name of my button. Can I remove the button using the string?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Basically you need to understand one thing. You cant remove a view based on its text. You need to find that view and then remove that view using View object but not by using String object

Comment: @SaiPhani Thanks. I got it now, I just compared the string to the object. See the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! So, because I have only a string, I can just check to see if that string equals the object:

```
if(myButtonName.equals("Blue")){

                    View myView = (View) findViewById(R.id.Blue);
                    ((ViewManager)v.getParent()).removeView(v);

                }
```

Then I can manually remove the object itself. Because, as Sai mentioned, it is impossible to remove a view with a string object; I just removed the view after checking it through an if statement, and replacing the object.

You can also use switch:

```
  switch(hello) {
                case "Blue":

                    View myView = (View) findViewById(R.id.Blue);
                    ((ViewManager) v.getParent()).removeView(v);

                    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why won't you do it this way??**

```
View namebar = view.findViewById(R.id.namebar);
((ViewGroup) namebar.getParent()).removeView(namebar);
```

Comment: He doesn't have a view object to begin with, he is trying to remove a view with string object

Comment: yup...thats he can do it this way ....why take the hard way?? what are his requirements??

Comment: I can't do it this way. As mentioned in the question, I only have a String, and I want to delete the view group based on the string

Comment: @SaiPhani I have a string. That string is also the variable name of my button. Can I remove the button using the string?

Comment: If you have the view and want to remove it....get the view and delete it why use String??

Comment: @RuchirBaronia you cant remove a view with `String` object you need a `View` object in order to remove it.

Comment: @johnrao07 i guess he doesn't have a `View`

Comment: well button is a view

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly cast `String` to `View` or `ViewGroups` but you can try this method:

- Check all button name and compare it with you button name . Use
  `button.getText()` to get the text of button and then compare it with
  your button name "myButton".
- If a match found, remove that button using your `removeView(Button)`.
  Else, ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I couldn't understand that why you have to reversely to find a view from a string. Still, whatever condition you are in, I am answering your question.

I read your answer too, it might give you desired output, but I feel the approach is wrong.

So, you have a String having the button's id name. So, you can get it's resource_identifier(int) from the string. like

```
String btnName = "btn_test";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(btnName, "id", getPackageName());
Button btnTest = (Button)findViewById(id);
```

So, once you got a `btnTest` holding the `View`, you can remove it. With this method you won't need to hardcode anything. Hope this helps..